# Updating content Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want to make a feature for my web app in laravel(i'm new at it) that every Post/Comment/Theme(in my case) the user has the ability to upVote and downVote. Now i am woking with upVote, but it is not working whatsoever.

In the view (welcome.blade.php) 
I have:

```
<a href="{{ route('Voteplus', ['name' => $Theme->name]) }}"> <img class="media-object" style="height:40px; width:40px;" src="images/upVote.svg" alt="..."></a>
```

Where $Theme->name is the one that the user wants to upVote/like(whatsoever).

The route:

```
Route::put('/', [
'uses'=>'Vote@VotePlus',
'as' =>'Voteplus' //Name of route
    ]);
```

And the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\NewTheme;
use DB;
class Vote extends Controller {

    public function VotePlus($name){

    DB::table('New_Themes')
->where('name', $name)
->increment('upVotes', 1);

    $Themes = NewTheme::paginate(5);

    return redirect()->route('welcome', ['Themes'=>$Themes]);
}
    };
```

I am trying everything, but it isn't working. Can someone help me please?

Comment: `->where('title', $title)` should be `->where('title', $name)`?

Comment: I changed but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe the put route is wrong and I am using it all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With an anchor tag, you only send a get request. If you want it to be put, you must create a form, and then add :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I finally solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this issue is to use Ajax. Right now the page will get refreshed each time a user wants to up-vote a theme and that can be quite frustrating.

I think you should post to the back end using Ajax and on the success callback update the view with javascript. I recommend using [Angular](https://angularjs.org) for the front end. It has all what you need and it is super simple to make an Ajax-request.

So, here's a quick example how you could use Angular + Laravel to make your web application work.

**Front End**

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>MyTitle</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ThemeController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="theme in themes">
               <span><% theme.name %></span>
               <p><% theme.description %></p>
               <p><% theme.votes %></p>

               <a href="#" ng-click="voteUp(theme)">Vote Up</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module("exampleApp", [], function($interpolateProvider) {
            // This we need to not collide with Laravel's {{ }}
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
        });

        app.controller('ThemeController', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.themes = [];

            $scope.voteUp = function(theme) {
                $http({
                    url: '/api/themes/voteUp',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id: theme.id
                    }
                }).success(function(response) {
                    theme.votes += 1;
                });
            }

            // On init we need to get the themes
            $http({
                url: '/api/themes',
                method: 'GET'
            }).success(function(themes) {
                $scope.themes = themes;
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Back End**

Your routes

```
Route::get('api/themes', 'ThemeController@getFive');
Route::post('api/themes/voteUp, 'ThemeController@voteUp');
```

Your ThemeController

```
function getFive() {
    return Theme::paginate(5);
}

function voteUp(Request $request) {
    $theme = Theme::whereId($request->id);
    $theme->votes += 1;
    $theme->save();

    return $theme;
}
```

This code is not tested. But I'll think you get the point!

Comment: I changed a little bit, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad I could help